# Most Powerful Test for random variable with different distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, neyman-pearson-lemma

#### The exercise

We have $\Theta = \{0,1\}$ and let $X$ be a random variable with density function $f(x;0)=1$ and $f(x;1)=3x^2$ for $x\in (0,1)$. I want to find the most powerful test of size $\alpha=0.2$ for the testing problem: $H_0: \theta=0$ vs $H_1: \theta=1.$

I have done a similar exercise for a given discrete distribution, but this one is quite different.

#### What I have done so far

My first thoughts were to let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from $X$, and then search for a critical region
$$R=\left\{\underset{\sim}{X}: \frac{f_1(\underset{\sim}{X})}{f_0(\underset{\sim}{X})} > k\right\} ,$$ and then choose $k$ such that $P_{\theta_0}(\underset{\sim}{X} \in R)=\alpha.$

The ratio can then be calculated as

$$\frac{f_1(\underset{\sim}{X})}{f_0(\underset{\sim}{X})} = \frac{f_1(\underset{\sim}{X};1)}{f_0(\underset{\sim}{X};0)} = 3 \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2,$$

and therefore

$$P_{\theta_0}\left\{ \frac{f_1(\underset{\sim}{X})}{f_0(\underset{\sim}{X})}>k\right\} =P_{\theta_0}\left\{3 \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 >k\right\}.$$

This is where I become stuck, so I would really appreciate some feedback on a) if I have done the right stuff so far, and b) How I should now proceed.

Comment: How do you get a sum in $X_i^2$ when evaluating $f_1$? Can you elaborate the steps there?

Comment: I was thinking since we had many random samples, but I now believe it becomes sufficient to use just one random sample, which in this case gives a final $k=1.92$. Does that make sense? @Glen_b

Comment: I'm sorry but you have missed the point. Keep all $n$ points in the [sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(statistics)). How did you get a **SUM** there: $\frac{f_1(\underset{\sim}{X};1)}{f_0(\underset{\sim}{X};0)} = 3 \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2,$ You very much need to *justify* that step.

Comment: Ah it should be a product of $X_i$s...

Comment: Be careful, though, that's not the only thing to worry about there.

Comment: Based on the problem statement, looks to me there is just a single observation $X$, so sample size is $1$. It is clear that the ratio $f_1/f_0$ is increasing in $x$, so...